# Bayesian Analysis: Number of Samples Produced from the Posterior

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian

I am learning about Bayesian analysis from some slides that were handed down to me (as opposed to a proper textbook on the subject). My knowledge on the subject is thus limited, but I was hoping to get some help in understanding what the following means.

The slides have the following paragraph:

> Note that the original analysis produced 4,000 samples from the posterior distribution. For a given sample (which is a list of possible parameter values), a predicted value is simulated for each of the 3,000 policies and then they are summed.

I don't understand where the $4000$ is coming from here. The quote above is referring to a dataset of $6000$ data points, which was divided into 2 training and testing datasets, each containing $3000$ data points. How did we end up with a $1000$ extra "samples from the posterior distribution"?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using a genuine textbook, many of which are available on line for free. See, e.g. [Bayes Rules!](https://www.bayesrulesbook.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this book, which is free on-line:  [http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/)

Without more context, I can't be sure of this answer, but it is likely that:

1. You had 6,000 data points which were observations of some physical process ($X$)
2. There were 4,000 Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) samples drawn from the appropriate distributions to form the posterior sample given the data.

The 4,000 MCMC samples are about the model parameters, while the 6,000 data points are about the process outputs.

Generally, the posterior probability distribution over the parameters given the data ($f(\theta|X)$) is proportional to the prior distribution over the parameters ($f(\theta)$) times the likelihood of the data given the parameters ($f(X|\theta)$).

$$f(\theta|X)\ \propto\ f(\theta)f(X|\theta)$$